# Load image to imageView from Firabse Storage Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to load an image to an imageView from firebase storage as expected.

I have the below function that is called in viewDidLoad but not sure why it's not working.

I copied the urlName.com directly from the image within Firebase storage.

```
func setProfileImage() {

    let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://urlName.com").child("Folder/\(currentUserID).jpg").getData(maxSize: 1048576, completion: { (data, error) in

        guard let imageData = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    })
}
```

This code doesn't throw an error but also doesn't load anything.

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Allow Access for development mode, In `Storage` > `Rules`:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/yourapp.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Get the data:

```
let reference = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "your_folder_path)/image.jpg")
      reference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
        if let _error = error{
           print(_error)
      } else {
        if let _data  = data {
           let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
             self.profileImage.image = myImage
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: So now I'm actually getting an error in the console:

\\Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object gs:/appName.appspot.com/Users/ profileImage.jpg does not exist." UserInfo={object= gs:/appName.appspot.com/Users/ profileImage.jpg, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}

The odd thing is that the path shows “gs:/” in xcode but in the firebase console it’s actually “gs://” with two forward slashes.

Comment: There’s a white space in the profileImage.jpg and also make sure the file exists at that path

Comment: Ah the space I put was just an accident when I was editing the paragraph. Got it to work now thanks, turned out I was using the file path the starts from the root and not the child which withPath requires.

Thank you